# How to make or suggest good edits

Tags: discussion, faq, editing, suggested-edits

**What should I do when editing a post, or suggesting an edit?**

Math SE is a collaborative platform where almost anyone can contribute.  One way in which you can improve the site is by editing posts (questions or answers) written by others.  While the Help Center does provide some [guidance on editing](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit), this advice is primarily directed at users with over 2000 reputation, who are permitted to make edits without undergoing review.

The purpose of this FAQ is to expand on that advice, and also to give some guidance to users with less than 2000 reputation, who must have their suggested edits approved by other community members.

Comment: Suggested edits for tag wikis occasionally pop up, and the advice below is less suited for this. Perhaps something can be added?

Comment: @CalvinKhor I don't think that tag wiki edits are common enough nor distinct enough to merit extra discussion (to my mind, the only real distinction is that tag wikis don't "age", so any of the advice related to bumping old topics is less relevant---all of the other advice remains good).

Comment: Sure ok. Do edits to community wiki posts enter the queue as well? I would guess not, but the tag wikis are something like community wiki posts. There are some very barebones tag wikis and any reasonable edit might severely deviate from the original. There is also no issue of ‘context’ in the sense of amWhy’s comment as tag wikis don’t get closed (though a tag wiki might help justify the tag’s existence).

Comment: Indeed, maintaining the "voice" of the post is also less important, as tag wikis are essentially "authorless".  Again, I really don't think that it is a such a big deal---you aren't going to go wrong if you follow the advice given below, but tag wikis and community wiki posts can be edited a little more loosely.  Of course, if you feel that a separate answer is needed, you are welcome to provide such.

Comment: This needs to be enforce, sir Xander.  Else it's just words that, if people try to follow, when reviewing suggested edits, you find fault with them.  You protect suggested editors who violate your advice.

Answer (score 20):

#### When Editing

- **Consider the age of the post.**

  Whenever a post is edited, it is bumped to the top of the Active Questions list on the front page.  This crowds out other posts which are also deserving of attention.  If a question is relatively old and already has several answers, it likely doesn't need the renewed attention—such a post should not be edited unless the edit provides a *substantial* improvement to the question (e.g. edits to correct a single spelling error should probably be avoided).  On the other hand, smaller cosmetic edits to very new posts are more acceptable.
- **Make a noticeable improvement to the post.**

  Edits should typically be used to make significant, important improvements to a post.  When you make an edit, please ensure that the changes you are making actually make the post noticeably better.  This is particularly true in the case of posts which have been closed for lacking clarity, detail, or context—if you engage in editing such a question, make sure that the final product meets the guidelines outlined in the post [How to ask a good question.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) , and before editing a question to include additional context, please read the [Guidelines for context edits and rewrites](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32402/guidelines-for-context-edits-and-rewrites) .

  To avoid this, make sure that edits do as much as possible to clean up or correct a post.  If you edit a post to add a tag or to fix the formatting in a title, also check to see if there are other issues which need correcting:  correct spelling and grammar mistakes, improve the formatting of the mathematics, remove salutations, add necessary links, and so on.  When an edit is completed, the post should be up to the quality standards of the site.
- **Adhere to the original post's style.**

  Edits which significantly alter the original style of a post are discouraged.  For example, please do not replace `\lim_{x\to a}` ($\lim_{x\to a}$) with `\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}` ($\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}$) or `\lim\limits_{x\to a}` ($\lim_{x\to a}$) (or *vice versa*); don't change $\sin x$ to $\sin(x)$; don't Americanize or Britishify spellings (e.g. don't replace "color" with "colour" or *vice versa*); etc.  Please also note that there is a general guideline on the site to avoid titles which stretch the vertical spacing.  Thus the use of `\displaystyle`, `\dfrac`, `\dbinom`, etc in question titles is *strongly* discouraged.
- **Don't just remove "noise".**

  Greetings, salutations, goodbyes, and expressions of thanks are generally considered to be noise, and it is entirely appropriate to remove such noise from posts while making *other* significant edits.  However, please do not edit a post *just* to remove such noise.  For more details on this, please refer to the meta question [Deleting 'thanks for help' from posts](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32456/deleting-thanks-for-help-from-posts) .
- **Write a clear edit summary.**

  This is particularly true for users who have not yet accrued enough reputation to make edits without approval, but is good practice for everyone.  When an edit is made, there is a field for entering an edit summary, which should describe the edits being made.  This helps reviewers to understand why you are editing a post, and can help draw attention to seemingly small changes.  These edit summaries can also serve as guidance for the original poster, who might learn from the changes you make.
- **Limit the number of edits you make.**

  This is true both in a local sense, and in a global sense.

  In a local sense, do not make many edits to a single post.  As noted, every edit bumps the post to the top of the Active Questions list, and decreases the visibility of other posts.  This isn't fair to the users who have posted these questions, so please try to avoid excessive editing.  If a post is very complicated, you might consider using the [Sandbox for drafts of long, complex posts](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4666/sandbox-for-drafts-of-long-complex-posts) on Meta.  This can be a good place to get your thoughts clarified and the formatting worked out before making an edit (or posting a question or answer in the first place).

  In a global sense, try not to edit too many posts at once.  A good rule of thumb is that you should never bump more than one or two posts to the front page at the same time.  After editing one post, give it some time to fall off of the front page before editing another.  Or limit yourself to only four or five edits per day.

  In both cases, the goal is to ensure that everyone has fair access to the front page.

#### When Suggesting an Edit

All of the above guidelines hold when suggesting an edit, only more so.  While it might be acceptable for a grizzled veteran to make a small change to a very old post and leave a useless edit summary, new users who need to have their edits approved by the community should avoid this kind of editing.  When you suggest an edit, you are asking other users to take some time out of their day in order to review your work.  Please respect their time and suggest edits which make significant improvements, rather than minor cosmetic or quality-of-life alterations.

Comment: For the first point the ["Thanks"](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32456/deleting-thanks-for-help-from-posts) issue might worth some particular mention.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Good call.  I've added a bullet point, and a link to the previous discussion.

Comment: Are all of these facts about edit queue and front-page bumping just true for edits of others' posts, or also when you edit your own? I ask because I will sometimes review an answer I wrote a couple of weeks ago and tweak a word, or fix a spelling mistake. If these bump the post to the front page then I'll stop doing this (because I hate old questions that are front page bumped for minor edits). I know you say "written by others" at the top, but maybe repeat this in the "Limit the number .." section? I know it would clarify the issue for me.

Comment: Also, I very much appreciate your making explicit the distinction between fresh posts and old posts.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC Any time a post is edited, it jumps to the top of the front page, whether it was edited by the original poster or by someone else.  For this reason, one should be a little more cautious editing old posts, even if they are the original author.  On the other hand, bumping one post every month or two when you find a typo isn't a big deal, and "a couple of weeks old" is not that old.  This is more about preventing new users from making, say, 100 edits to change "continuos" to "continuous" across the site over the course of three days (and yes, this has happened).

Comment: @XanderHenderson- Thanks. I was pretty sure my activities were on the less intrusive side, but I appreciate the guidance.

Comment: I think also highly relevant to both suggested edits, and edits in general, are the [Guidelines for context edits and rewrites](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32402/guidelines-for-context-edits-and-rewrites).

Answer (score 6):

#### Editing Closed Questions

If a question has been closed, the first "major" edit of that question made within 70 days of closure will place that question to be placed in the "Reopen" review queue ([see here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256567/which-edits-push-closed-questions-to-the-reopen-review-queue/256572#256572), and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/196078/436415)—note that some of this information has been deprecated by changes to how the Reopen Review Queue works; please see the discussion below).  Subsequent edits will not return a closed question to the queue.

Thus, when editing closed questions, do one of the following:

1. Make sure that the edits that you make improve the question enough that it can be reopened.  Upon making edits which improve the post enough to enable reopening, check the "Submit for Review" box above the "Save Edits" button.  This will send the question to the Reopen Review Queue.  For details, please see [Review queue workflows - Final release](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369013/) on the main Meta site.

   [image]
2. If, instead, you choose to make minor edits (e.g. adding MathJax formatting, making small grammatical or spelling corrections, etc), do *not* check the "Submit for Review" box.  In such a case, please also consider helping the asker to understand *why* their question was closed, and think about how you might help them to improve their question so that it can be reopened.

Comment: Is this information  mentioned in the close box?

Comment: @VerónicaRmz. No.

Comment: Related: [Should I avoid minor edit of a question which was put on hold?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16820) (The accepted answer contains link to the relevant post on Meta Stack Overflow.)

Comment: The mechanism described here was recently change - an edit pushes a question into the reopen review queue only if the significant-edit-checkbox is checked, this does not automatically happen after the first edit as previously. The announcement on [meta.se]: [Review queue workflows - Final release](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369013).

Comment: @Xander  Time to review what you once, at least, claimed to support?