# Why was this question and its answer deleted, and how to undelete it?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I noticed by accident that the question
[Recurrence on partial orders [closed]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4247208/recurrence-on-partial-orders),
asked by user948104 on Sep 11, has been closed and deleted.
Along the question went also my answer, to which I had spent some effort.

From the content of the question and answer, honestly I see no reason for deleting them:

- The question is quite clear and meaningful. It received no upvotes but no downvotes either (net votes zero).
- My answer, as far as my judgment is relevant at all, is informative, friendly, contains pointers to literature, and directly answers the questions raised. It received one downvote (I have literally no idea why, but perhaps that is not my business).

Now my **questions** are: Looking at this record of deleted Q&A

1. How can one get **any information** on **why** they were deleted? The record says nothing more than "This question does not meet Mathematics Stack Exchange guidelines." which says absolutely nothing about the reason. (There is, for example, no hint that the question was considered a duplicate, nor do I personally think it is a duplicate.)
2. Is there any method for asking the question to be undeleted? I do not see any undelete button on it. If there was any visible method, I would not be posting here.

To be honest about it, I find this "no-visible-explanation-at-all" deletion perplexing, even downright rude, both towards the original asker and towards my efforts in answering it. Putting that aside, I see it as a disservice to other readers since the information provided in my answer has been taken out of view.

Comment: This is an automatic deletion (the post is closed, and both the question and the answer don't have positive score, and the answer is not accepted). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @Arctic Char. So if I understand correctly, had I just voted the question up myself, that +1 would have been enough to prevent the automatic deletion? Well I cannot upvote it anymore, so there it went down the drain. What about my second question?

Comment: You will need 3 10K+ users to vote to undelete the post. The post is closed as missing context, and indeed it is. The only context is really the definition of the partial order.

Comment: Yes, if it is undeleted, then an upvote would keep the post from autodeletion. But other users might vote to delete too, as long as the post is closed.

Comment: Well, the question provided the context of how far the numbers are known (nontrivial information) and a quite natural, meaningful question about whether one can extend them by recursion. I thought the question was interesting and merited a thoughtful answer, but apparently not.

Comment: I am confused by the post. Why is $P_{19}$ unknown? I just can't see what is special about $n=19$.

Comment: Are you confused by the question or by the answer? I thought my answer provides a quite understandable account on what is difficult about computing these numbers.

Comment: The question was closed.  The reason that the question was closed was articulated in the banner at the top of the question.  If a question is closed and not improved, then it is eligible to be deleted.  The reason for deletion is identical to the reason for closure.  In this case, the deletion was automatic, but posts deleted by a vote of users are *also* deleted without further comment.

Comment: Yes, the closing reason is "does not meet guidelines", which is a blanket statement.

Comment: I think my confusion is why exactly $n=19$. What makes $n=18$ computable while not $19$ for example?

Comment: The close reason is longer (not sure if you can see it) it saids: Please provide additional context, which ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and our community. Some forms of context include: background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, your current progress, why the question is interesting or important, etc.

Comment: Of course it is moot now, that the OP had deleted their account and will not be back to edit the post.

Comment: Arctic Char, are you in general familiar with combinatorial counting problems? This kind of phenomenon is nothing uncommon there. Indeed my very answer (deleted) contained an attempt to explain this thing.

Comment: No, I do not see that longer reason. All I see is "Closed. This question does not meet Mathematics Stack Exchange guidelines. It is not currently accepting answers." That glaring lack of any visible reason was indeed why I asked here.

Comment: Looks like the close reason is available to those who has 3k+ reps. Right now there are two un-delete votes on the post. I edited a bit, but I don't find the reference where $P_{17}, P_{18}$ are calculated.

Comment: That reference is right there in my answer. It is the Brinkmann & McKay paper. I would have edited the OEIS link to the question myself, but you know, I cannot edit it since it has been deleted and I have such low rep.

Comment: One more perplexing thing: I do see an Undelete button *on my answer*. I have no idea what is would even mean to undelete an answer when the question itself has been deleted. Would it be some kind of orphan answer-without-question?

Comment: Okay I see that now (I was tricked by the title of the paper). I added already the sequence in OEIS in the post.

Comment: You wouldn't have these problems, Jukka, if you took more care in selecting appropriate questions to answer.  If you choose to answer very low quality questions, then you risk having your answers deleted because that's what happens to very low quality questions.

Comment: Well I disagree about that being a "very low quality question".

Comment: The question has been **undeleted**.

Comment: Gerry: Thank you for the heads up. Now that the question is again visible to mortals, I see today's edit history, where two helpful users (Arctic Char and Mike) tried to make the question better by adding the OEIS link, and a third user removed it. Twice.

Comment: Per [the guidelines](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32402/guidelines-for-context-edits-and-rewrites), the edit was inappropriate.  Any user who believes that they can ask a better version of the question is free to do so.

Comment: @XanderHenderson actually, it’s not clear to me: which part of the editing guidelines did that edit violate? Could you please clarify?

Comment: @TheAmplitwist "Do not expand the question with so much context that it changes fundamentally. Doing so modifies the author's intent by presuming the author's level of sophistication and mathematical maturity."  Adding a reference to the OEIS suggests the original asker was familiar with that database, and searched it.  This changes the context of the question, as it suggests greater mathematical maturity than seems to be on display in that question.

Comment: That's just hilarious. If the asker knew enough to say that the numbers are available to $n=18$, the most obvious thing is that they indeed *got that information from the OEIS* but simply did not understand or remember to put that link in their post. (Sure, it is possible that they got the information from somewhere else but ... not bleaking likely. And would not matter anyway: this way or that, the OP had that maturity.) To imply that helping them out by adding that forgotten link is "suggesting greater mathematical maturity" and "changing the question fundamentally" is ... it's just rich.

Comment: In fact, the very guidelines linked above say this: "You can add in relevant definitions, theorems, or simple background and motivation. You can add a source for the question." The question already contained the information (about numbers being available to $n=18$); all that these two helpful users were doing was adding a source reference for that *already existing information*.

Comment: Why would i care about a deleted accounts maturity? @xander (I asked the same question in the editing guideline). Now the post has absolutely nothing to do with them.

Comment: @JukkaKohonen In previous comment, you complained that context standards are meaningless because people often get away with posting terrible, contextless questions.  We have a policy which asks users not to fundamentally change the context of posts.  You cannot possibly know that the original asker was looking at the OEIS, or that they even know that it exists.  You are making a rather large assumption.  Maybe they were reading one of the papers cited in that OEIS entry.  Maybe they have a mean-spirited combinatorics instructor who assigned this as homework.  We simply don't know.

Comment: Also, i dont think adding a link to their claim changes the post fundamentally.

Comment: We have a policy that such edits are inappropriate.  I am uniformly enforcing that policy.  I do not understand how you can complain that context standards are not upheld on the one hand, and yet ask me to disregard another policy on the other.

Comment: Frankly, it would almost certainly take you less time to post a new question and ask for a moderator to move the answer (or just copy-paste the answer, assuming that the question was already deleted)  than you have taken to argue with me about site policies which you clearly disagree with.

Comment: @ArcticChar Aside from the fact that I am trying to uniformly enforce a policy, the addition of a single link does nothing to motivate the problem, and really does not add much context to the question.  It is a poor question, period---whether or not the underlying mathematics is interesting.  There is no indication of why anyone should care about the answer, nor about where it came from (again, a link to the OEIS does not necessarily align with the author's original intent), nor about what the actual asker of the question knows or understands.

Comment: Edits should [make a noticeable improvement to the post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/33019/).  Adding a link to a source which is of dubious relevance to the original author's intent does *not* make a noticeable improvement.

Comment: I will point out, just for the record, that Mike Earnest proposed an alternative question which has the same mathematical content, but which essentially adheres to the standards of the site.  He asked, point blank, if that would be a sufficient question.  I said that I think it *would* be.  It would take someone all of 30 seconds to copy that text, post a new question, and ask for a merge.  Personally, I don't think that Mike's version is *wonderful*, and I would find the process of merging distasteful, but I would merge the questions and wash my hands of this whole thing.

Comment: So I really have to wonder... what is the *goal* of the argumentation here?  What outcome are the partisans seeking?

Comment: Well, *my* goals should have been clear already from my Meta question, if one reads it plainly without assuming ulterior motives or "partisanship" (what a nice word). I was genuinely seeking to understand the underlying reasons for closing and deleting such mathematical content from the site. Having now seen them, I am better informed and now I better understand the state that Math.SE is in. This is good for me so I can better *select* where I think it is reasonable to disseminate mathematical knowledge, and where it clearly is not.

Comment: "We have a policy that such edits are inappropriate." No, @Xander, we have a policy *that you interpret* as saying that such edits are inappropriate. Since you have a diamond, your interpretation wins, but it's clear from this comment stream that more than one user has a very different interpretation. It might be worth keeping this in mind.

Comment: @XanderHenderson: You have consistently shown that your interpretation of the editing guidelines is very different from their originally intended meaning and the consensus of pretty much everyone else who reads them.  You really should stop claiming that you are just enforcing what is written there.

Comment: Question (and answer) have now been **redeleted**.

Comment: And now once again **undeleted**.

Comment: Jukka, more often than not we use [this thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/32975/11619) to draw more attention to a case where different reviewers hold opposing views. I realize that some of the problems you detected are due to your still relatively low rep score. After you reach 10000 points, what you see will change. Not ideal, but them's the breaks.

Comment: I also want it on record that I am not criticizing Xander's actions here. I acted/voted the way I did, because I seek to keep new mathematical content visible. If the question had been a homework problem, I would vote to delete it on any excuse. A good answer notwithstanding. Xander (and many other voters) don't give this difference much weight at all, which is fine. For otherwise they could not efficiently deal with the volume of questionable content the site receives.

Comment: Actually I now think my chosen action is not within the guideline on context edits/rewrites. Given that the original asker's account has been deleted, may be we can think of the current version of the question as a crowd sourced version? I certainly don't want my name attached to a rewritten version of the question. I doubt Mike Earnest or Jukka Kohonen wants their name attached to a rewritten version either. Ideally we might pass ownership to the famous user number -1, but a deleted account will do just as well I think.

Comment: Still, I am uncomfortable with the thought of having added an exception to that guideline. You see, that opens the door for other exceptions, eventually voiding the guideline. Arrggh, I have more pressing things to think about. May be later?

Comment: One more thing. The list Jukka produced (see the search link in his answer) contains near duplicates. There is some variation between the questions, but I think some dupe closing is also needed.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen "I am not criticizing Xander's actions here."  Just to be clear, I have taken exactly *one* action with respect to this question:  when the system automatically raised a rollback war flag, I reverted the question to the state in which it was left by the asker.  I have been active in the *discussion* here, but I have taken no action aside from that.

Comment: And I have now taken a second action:  I have converted the question to community wiki.  The argument has been made that the original asker is no longer around, and so the context edit / rewrite guidelines do not apply.  While I disagree, I think that removing ownership from the original account is an acceptable alternative.

Comment: @Jyrki: Yes, I can see that Math.SE withholds a lot of information from low-rep users; when answering a question, they do not even see that someone is already voting to close the question; they are not informed that their answer was deleted; they are not given any kind of information on why it was deleted (the "close reason"). In order to be worth such decent treatment, one has to collect enough brownie points *first*.

Comment: I have deleted my answer; seems like the most correct thing to do, given how unwelcoming Math.SE is to mathematical content if it does not jump through exactly the correct hoops (about which the high-rep users are in fact in disagreement). As a sweetener you get punitive downvotes on your *answer* (and perhaps also on your *other* answers) if you give a perfectly reasonable answer to a 
*question* that someone does not like. Apparently the question and my answer inadvertently hit some spots of local politics that have little to do with mathematics.

Comment: @JukkaKohonen What is on-topic/acceptable for MSE and what is not has little to do with mathematics(but will still affect the day-to-day lives of all MSE users). That is precisely why 90% (underestimating) of all main site users don't engage in meta, because everybody would rather contribute math on the main site than argue about these things on the meta site, and they ignore occasional closures/downvotes because on the whole they feel their content is being retained and rewarded. That category of people is IMO most satisfied with the site and benefit most (mathematically) from it.

Comment: The trouble is that the SE model doesn't fit well with what one would like to demand from MSE : policies such as high reputation having privileges , any(not just low-rep) user not being informed of closure/deletion (which was defended with a feeble "we don't believe in overly nagging people" at the time by an SE member and never found implementation), and high-rep users being able to see closed/deleted questions etc. clearly biases against low-rep users. So we are also grappling with the SE model not fitting our own sense of site ethics. This is the system.

Comment: @JukkaKohonen A very sad ending. Especially to those who tried to preserve your answer. I hope you reconsider and un-delete your answer.

Comment: "Yes, I can see that Math.SE withholds a lot of information from low-rep users."  For better or worse, that is the SE model.  It is not a perfect system, and (as is true with any group of people) it takes time to learn the rules.  I would like to encourage you to undelete your answer, as a lot of folk here have put a lot of time, effort, and emotional energy into preserving it.

Comment: @Teresa, I can understand the challenges due to the SE model, but I doubt that the model *necessarily* mandates a condescending attitude towards well-meaning and reasonable answers. As to whether I see my effort being retained and rewarded, I don't think so. Quite the contrary. I see a determined effort in keeping it out, deleting and re-deleting, along with the question, and in preventing the question from being improved. This, even if the written instructions encourage people to improve questions.

Comment: @JukkaKohonen I can understand the point about the addition of context because I felt it was done properly (by Jyrki) and I voted to reopen the question, so I was able to exercise my right, as you were able to by creating this meta post and making us aware of the situation. I think the clash of opinion is honestly not going to go away, but it seems it is the condescending manner of speech that seems to have taken center stage here, and that should not be happening. Your answer can be undeleted by one more vote.

Comment: Arctic Char and Teresa: I am touched by your concern of losing the efforts of those who edited the *question*. (Oh, nobody expressed any concern of *my* answering efforts going down the drain; au contraire, that is the just reward for answering such questions. I am not making this up: you can see this in the comments above.) But I don't see the point of the concern: I was *not* deleting the question, so the efforts of its editors were quite preserved, intact, all the time (except at the point when someone rolled them back but that was not me).

Comment: But I have undeleted my answer. Not because of any concern of anybody's efforts, certainly not those of mine (I understand that is not a concern on Math.SE). But because I think my answer may actually be useful to some readers. (Yes, I think this, despite the three undoubtedly deserved downvotes on the answer, saying that *it is not useful*. I have no doubts that the voters are going to openly point out the flaws of the answer and are right now busy composing a better answer.)

Comment: @JukkaKohonen "Oh, nobody expressed any concern of my answering efforts going down the drain".  I very much disagree.  I have expressed concerns for your efforts from the start.  I suggested that repost a better version of question and copy your answer over (Mike Earnest proposed a reasonable version), and I encouraged you to undelete your answer (in part to preserve your own effort, and also to respect the efforts of those that worked hard to preserve your content).  Frankly, had you *not* answered the question, I don't think that anyone would have bothered to defend the question itself.

Comment: In that respect, **everyone** who had voted to undelete the question, or offered advice on improving the question, or described procedures for reposting low-quality questions has been expressing concern for *your* efforts (as the original asker certainly didn't make much of an effort).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> From the content of the question and answer, honestly I see no reason for deleting them.

The question was closed for [lack of context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/177399). Questions which are closed and meet [certain criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/285880) are later automatically deleted.

In my opinion, sufficient context would be something along the lines of *"I am a combinatorics student/I am self studying combinatorics/I saw this YouTube video about combinatorics. Looking at the OEIS sequence for the number of partial orders on a finite set, we see that the terms are only computed up to $n=18$. I have seen many other combinatorial sequences which can be computed recursively from previous terms, like the Bell numbers. Is there a way to do this with the number of partial orders?"*

> My answer, as far as my judgment is relevant at all, is informative, friendly, contains pointers to literature, and directly answers the questions raised.

Your answer was deleted simply because the question was. This can be avoided by not answering no-context questions. If you find a question that you have an interesting answer for, you can comment to try to encourage the user to provide context. In some cases, you can fix a low-quality question by editing it yourself. (You have 2,000 reputation, so you have this privilege).

> [My answer] received one downvote (I have literally no idea why, but perhaps that is not my business).

Often, people will downvote answers when they are in response to a question they think is low quality, as a strategy to discourage people from answering low-quality questions. Your answer is quite informative and well-written, so this is the only reason for the downvote I can imagine.

> How can one get any information on why they were deleted? The record says nothing more than "This question does not meet Mathematics Stack Exchange guidelines."

You cannot see the close reason because you have [less than 3,000 reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions0).

> Is there any method for asking the question to be undeleted?

Once you reach [10,000 reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools), you get access to the delete/undelete vote.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130297/discussion-on-answer-by-mike-earnest-why-was-this-question-and-its-answer-delete).

Comment: To wrap up the answer to my question 1: No, it is not possible (for a low-rep user) to see any reason beyond the blanket "it's closed". In anything visible to such user, there is not the slightest hint of *what* would have been wrong. Now whether this is just as it should be is another issue, but I'm happy to learn that this is how it is. This is one nice meta-message sent to low-rep users ("you don't deserve to see a reason").

Comment: @JukkaKohonen It's perhaps worth noting that the question asker does see more information. Details about the differences in the notices are available in the following post on [meta.se]: [New Post Notices are live network-wide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339700/986753).

Comment: "Often, people will downvote answers when they are in response to a question they think is low quality, as a strategy to discourage people from answering low-quality questions." Also as a strategy to make it easier to delete the question.

Comment: I edited in a segment from Mike's suggestion as well as a link to OEIS. Let's see if we can get this undeleted.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Not just undeleted : it's been reopened as well. I'm happy with your context rewrite, so I went for the reopening despite having deleted it earlier. I usually have doubts over how much one is "putting words in the mouth" of the OP, but this feels (I can't justify it) natural in some sense. Can you provide a more "in the spirit of the guidelines" justification? I would say that this counts as "*simple* background", which is why I agree with it, but I'd like to know why you went for it, given that context rewrites  are usually done with a "rare circumstance" caveat.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon I appreciate your vote of confidence. I'm afraid I cannot completely justify my choice of action within the spirit of that guideline. You see, I have a personal history of overediting questions like this a bit. I have not unlearned all old habits to the extent that a strict interpretation of the guideline would not apply. In fact, I would not have been surprised to be overruled by some voters.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks for your comment, I'd like to say I'm fine with what's happened. I wouldn't have voted to open if the edit wasn't made, but the question following it is better, essentially because I get from the OEIS why the sequence is special and needs attention, and is not any other run-of-the-mill sequence.

Comment: A few small factors. The question is in a sense about an open problem, totally unlike a botched homework question. The account of the asker has been deleted, so I could also follow the route of rewriting a better version. But I'm not sure I could do an essentially better job, so that would feel very contrived. Also, it sounds like Jukka's answer tells everything there is to know about this, so there is little sense having another thread about the theme. None of these are mentioned in the guideline. I'm not sure they should. Just my personal feeling that could and possibly should be criticized.