# What Are Meta and Main English Grammar and Formatting Standards for Stack Exchange Math English and Web Presentation?

Tags: support, editing, titles

Sometimes there are edits made to my questions and answers, adjusting capitalization for instance in a title from one of my questions.

I referred that editor to the grammarly site's [Capitalization in Titles: Rules](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/capitalization-in-the-titles/) page since [grammarly has the University backing of Washington University in St. Louis according to their main site page](https://www.grammarly.com), as a reference to their proper grammar application.

When I search for Math Stack Exchange grammar reference, I found in a web-search the article [How do I ask a good question? - Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for the main Stack Exchange website that has an interesting example:

> **Good:** How can I redirect users to different pages based on session data in PHP?

The grammarly site states that most words of an article title are capitalized, referencing a few style standards to choose from.

Searching on the Math Exchange Meta site does not result in any result for me about English Grammar.

But on the Main Stack Overflow Help Page, it is stated:

> #### I want to ask on Stack Overflow, but I don't speak English very
> well
>
> That's OK! We don't expect your English to be perfect. Even native
> speakers can make mistakes.
>
> All we ask is that you **try your best**. As long as you write your
> post in the best English you can, and we are able to make sense out of
> what you are trying to say, we will help you to [edit and improve your
> post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing). Many members of our community have excellent English skills,
> and they are happy to help you by improving your grammar/spelling or
> even rewriting some sentences.

Unfortunately here, on the Math Stack Exchange Site, edits can be made, but they require who-knows-what reputation to actually allow changes to proceed.  For instance, on [my question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/37304/revisions), I do not seem to have any option to up-vote a suggested edit. On the main [Stack Exchange Site on Editing Help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) it seems different:

> #### Who makes sure that proposed edits are good?
>
> Any user can
> propose edits, but not all edits are publicly visible immediately. 
> If a user has less than 2,000 reputation, 
> the [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) is
> placed in a review queue. Two accept or reject votes are required to
> remove the suggested edit from the queue and either apply the edit to
> the post or discard it.
>
> Users with more than 2,000 reputation are considered trusted community
> members, and can [edit posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) without going through the review
> process. The original author of a question or answer may always edit
> their own post, regardless of reputation level.

Right now I feel that the English standards on this site are a little bit different than standard English references, which is confusing, since the main Stack Exchange Site suggests that standard English should be used on the one hand.  But on the other hand standard English references to article titles, for instance, do not seem to apply and there is no guide here to reference in a comment.

Also, it seems to me that the edit-approval process to assist correcting English Grammar is quite a bit more difficult, since I am not finding the approval arrow for recommended edits, and I suppose that no one else can either.  Even in this post, I am having difficulty formatting "[suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit)", having tried a couple of attempts at adjusting the text inside the quotation, but I do not have confidence that someone could edit this post and then I could accept the edit because of the way the Math Stack Exchange Main and Meta system is setup.

In summary, there are two issues:

1. Standard English grammar (especially on this site) is different from other English standards, like for instance article titles, and it is hard to find an English grammar reference on this site that can be linked to a comment to help those correcting English.
2. Even after correcting small English typos, it requires who-knows-what reputation level here, which seems very high, and there is no obvious way to up-vote the edits for regular users who are English-prolific (or even web-site prolific to correct presentation issues like I had referenced previously).

I appreciate any support from the community (since both issues seem to require sufficient reputation and authority to correct or to get help with).

Comment: Please see related [How to make or suggest good edits](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33018/72031).

Comment: Re your summary point one: Standard English is different to Standard American English, although there are many similarities between the two (example difference: where the punctuation goes when quoting) and you should probably be specific about which you have in mind.  Secondarily: mathematical English is a jargon (in the technical sense) and applying Standard Am/Eng rules will only get you so far.  Reading journal articles (on the arxiv if nowhere else) is probably the best way to get exposure to the expected standard.

Comment: I'm not sure that I consider a Question Header to be the grammatical equivalent of an Article Title.  But...what's your question?  Are you proposing to edit other users' headers to comport with this proposed standard?  Or just curious as to the standards in effect?  If the latter, I'd say that grammatical style is much less formal here than it would be in a journal article.

Comment: @lulu For [my question, "My answer was downvoted but my algebra seems perfect. Where is the error??"](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/37304/revisions) and Martin suggested a title "answer algebra seems Where is the error??" (with strike out marks visible in the revision link).  Towards the right, Bill's edit to the question title is: "My answer was downvoted but my algebra seems perfect. Where is the error??" Not to be too picky, but the word downvoted is showing up as a problem with the spell-checker OK w/ "down-voted" and the title is lower-case, different from grammarly. Edit it?

Comment: Not following. Are you just asking about a single edit or proposing a general approach?  The current question doesn't even mention the prior one...  As a general rule, I would advise not editing other users' posts to correct minor stylistic errors.

Comment: If you disagree with the changes to your question, you may rollback those changes and/or make further edits.

Comment: Questions aren't articles, so, that expectation is the first surface issue to get past. We don't do articles, we do Q&A, that's it. If you don't know the reputation requirement for a privilege, [go and check for yourself](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges). For edits in particular, it is entirely unsurprising that [there's a piece on edits in particular](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/review-suggested-edits).

Comment: @StephenElliott In your comment you mention me - but if you [actually check the revision history](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/37304/revisions), I did not edit the title, only the tags. (If it helps, perhaps you can try several options for viewing differences: Inline, Side-by-side and Side-by-side Markdown).